# jConfirm on ajax success

Tags: ajax, jconfirm

I am using jConfirm for confirm dialog with success.

For first time i tried to call it inside the ajax success but seems to fail.

Here is the code:

```
    success: function (j) {   
    if(j.status)
    {

     jConfirm('File Already exist.Are you sure you want to replace ?', 'File Exist', function(r) {
         if (r==true)
      {   }
      else 
      {  
               //code for cancel
      }
     });
    }
  }//success
```

The problem is that the dialog is show but does not wait for user answer and continues.

When change to classic javascript confirm everything works fine!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`jConfirm` is an asynchronous method.
As you've noticed, it returns immediately, without waiting for the user to close the dialog.

You need to put all of your code in the `jConfirm` callback.

Comment: I am not quite follow you.function(r) is the callback.Am i missing something

Comment: @ntan: Any code after the `jConfirm` call should be put in the callback.